# Alpha hull with island

Tags: python, shapely, concave-hull

I need the 'concave hull' or alphashape of a set of points. Also, I'd like to have it with holes/donuts/islands in the middle. See my attached image. The outer hull is being calculated fine. But the large islands in the middle are generated as part of the hull. I want to get rid of that.

My code (partially grabbed from tutorials all around) can be found here: https://gist.github.com/willemvanopstal/f199c2f839b4de2abadfafde450c45ed

[image]

I expect it to be a simple mistake from my side.. Maybe in generating the resulting polygon from the isolated edges; (edge_points are the edges which have passed the alpha-test)

```
m = geometry.MultiLineString(edge_points)
triangles = list(polygonize(m))
return cascaded_union(triangles), edge_points
```

Is there anybody who knows a fix for my issue?

Comment: Have you considered to make separate alpha hulls for the outer ring and inner rings and compute difference as the final step?

Comment: @user30184 That's what I'd do.

Comment: This won't work with point features.  Your set of points won't have any defined 'inner' or 'outer' geometry because it is just a bunch of points.  Points aren't organized into inner and outer geometries like polygons.